# Create Excel Contact database

Tags: excel, contacts

I would like to create a database based on the following reasoning:

I want to assign to each contact I have some tags for his abilities, for example, so there will be a column called "abilities". So I was thinking about creating a list of possible abilities (probably on a second sheet), lets say "play football", "cook", "ride a bike" and define that "Mike" can "play football.

For this to be useful I would also like to know how it is possible to be able to filter my contacts by ticking on the list of abilities I am looking for.

Comment: What have you tried?  This is a bit too general for here: generally questions are about specific issues with existing code.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways to tackle this.

1) Make a table that has contacts and abilities all together.  This means that you will repeat the contact info if a person has multiple abilities.  Each row will be the unique combination of contact + ability. If you want to limit the options for ability to specific choices, create your list of abilities and use data validation to create a drop-down list of these values in your abilities column.

2) Make 3 tables: 1-Contact, 2-Abilities, 3-Map of Contacts to Abilities (each row contains the unique identifier for a contact and the unique identifier for an ability). I'm not sure if you really intend to make a database or just something in Excel that works. If you can use PowerPivot, that would be a good solution without needing another application to create your db. Bring your 3 tables into PowerPivot. Create a relationship between table 3 and table 1.  Create a relationship between table 3 and table 2.